# Create an Istio Virtual Service with Kafka in EKS

Tags: apache-kafka, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks, istio

can someone help me?

I'm currently have an EKS cluster with Apache Pinot installed and I configured with Istio a gateway and the virtual service. It works.

Now I installed a Apache Kafka in EKS and with Pinot it still works, but I want to create a consumer API to ingest into the kafka cluster in EKS.

When I tried to expose kafka as I exposed Pinot it doesn't work, it always shows me a message like

[image]

and that's a Pinot message.

I locally expose the Kafka with

```bash
kubectl port-forward kafka-controller-0 9092:9092
```

I expect to see something like
[image]

And I know this work 'cause with kafka_confluent I can reach the kafka cluster.

My Pinot and kafka virtual services are:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: pinot-ui
spec:
  hosts:
  - MyHost
  gateways:
  - my-gateway
  http:
  - name: "Pinot"
    match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /
    rewrite:
      uri: /
    route:
    - destination:
        host: pinot-controller
        port:
          number: 9000

#KAFKA

apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: kafka
spec:
  hosts:
  - MyHost
  gateways:
  - my-gateway
  http:
  - name: "kafka-cluster"
    match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /kafka
    route:
    - destination:
        host: kafka
        port:
          number: 9092
```

Finally my services are:

[image]

and my pods are:
[image]